# How to confirm embeded device(running android OS) whether has a speaker or not

Tags: android, speaker

I want to confirm embeded device(running android OS 5.1.1) whether has a speaker or   not.
I try AuidoManager#isSpeakerphoneOn, no matter I insert or remove speaker, it always return false。

I'm wondering how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**`PackageManager`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html) class' [`PackageManager#hasSystemFeature(String)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#hasSystemFeature(java.lang.String)) to check whether the given feature is present or not at runtime.

More specifically, you can query `PackageManager#hasSystemFeature(String)`  using the constant [`FEATURE_AUDIO_OUTPUT`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#FEATURE_AUDIO_OUTPUT) which returns true if the device includes at least one form of audio output, such as speakers, audio jack or streaming over bluetooth.

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
if(pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_AUDIO_OUTPUT){
  // audio output device present
} else {
  // no audio output device present
}
```

Or, you can also use the [`<uses-feature>`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html) element in the *AndroidManifest.xml* with `android:name` set to `android.hardware.audio.output` and `require` equals to `true` which will prevent your app from being installed on devices with no audio output device.

Answer (score 0):

You can put a  to only install on devices with a way of outputting sound.  I don't think there is an API to tell if it currently has a speaker.